# How to convert .csv label by python?

Tags: python, label, sklearn-pandas

I have a .csv label and have four different categories.

and now my .csv file looks like this:

id type

1   1

2   2

3   3

4   4

5   2

...

I want to convert it to like:

id  type1   type2  type3  type4

1   1        0       0      0

2   0        1       0      0

3   0        0       1      0

4   0        0       0      1

5   0        1       0      0

how can I done these via python? I use pd.read_csv()

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If your csv-file (named here `file.csv`) looks like

```
id,type
1,1
2,2
3,3
4,4
5,2
```

then you could use [`.str.get_dummies()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html) to do

```
df = (
    pd.read_csv("file.csv", index_col=0)
    .type.astype(str).str.get_dummies().rename(lambda c: f"type{c}", axis=1)
)
```

to get the following dataframe

```
    type1  type2  type3  type4
id                            
1       1      0      0      0
2       0      1      0      0
3       0      0      1      0
4       0      0      0      1
5       0      1      0      0
```

If you want to write that back to a new csv-file, then

```
df.to_csv("file_new.csv", index=True)
```

produces the following file `file_new.csv`:

```
id,type1,type2,type3,type4
1,1,0,0,0
2,0,1,0,0
3,0,0,1,0
4,0,0,0,1
5,0,1,0,0
```

Comment: wow ! Thanks for that answer! although i have already use simple if-else to solve that . Anyway, Thanks a lot!